# Complex Integration with Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$ have radius of convergence $R>0.$

Use the fact that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_\gamma c_n z^ndz=\int_\gamma \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^ndz=\int_\gamma f(z)dz$$  to show that 
$$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}dz \qquad(0<r<R)$$
where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $r$ centred at the origin, traversed once in the positive direction.

From the information given, I could construct a parametrisation $\gamma(t)=re^{it}$, then $\gamma '(t)=rie^{it}$. Using the identities gives, I could isolate the $c_k$ term by moving all other terms to the other side of the equality. Since $f(z)$ is in the final expression, I considered starting with 
$$\int_\gamma c_kz^kdz=\int_\gamma f(z)dz-\int_\gamma c_0dz-\cdots-\int_\gamma c_{k-1}z^{k-1}dz-\int_\gamma c_{k+1}z^{k+1}dz-\cdots-\int_\gamma c_nz^ndz$$
And I thought maybe the $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ term came from using the parametrisation with $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

But I'm not sure this is a good idea. I end up with a LHS looking like: 
$$c_k\left(\frac{r^2\left(e^{2i\pi (k+1)}-1\right)}{k+1}\right)$$
It's a little hopeful since the $z^{k+1}$ term could be of the form $re^{i(k+1)}$, but over all looking too messy. Especially since I can't think of a way to simplify the RHS either.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n}{z^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{\gamma} \frac{c_nz^n}{z^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n \int_{\gamma} z^{n-k-1}
$$

and now refer to the result that

$$
\int_{\gamma} z^m dz=
\begin{cases}
2 \pi i & \text{if} \; m=-1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

So

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n \int_{\gamma} z^{n-k-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot 2\pi i\cdot c_k=c_k
$$

as the integrals vanish unless $n=k$